# Entity Framework Seed method issue

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity

I have a database called 'shop'.... i'm trying to add some data into it using the 'seed' method.... this is how my seed method looks like....

```
public class ContextSeeder : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context>
{
    protected override void Seed(Context con)
    {
        User u1 = new User()
        {
            Email = "dayan@gmail.com",
            Password = "190"
        };

        con.Users.Add(u1);
        con.SaveChanges();
        base.Seed(con);
    }
}
```

my DBContext class looks like this.....

```
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public Context()
            : base("Context")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context>());

        }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ShoppingCart> ShoppingCarts { get; set; }
    }
```

this is how my 'user' class looks like....

```
public class User
{
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
}
```

I need this data to be stored when the database is created...... But it won't insert this data(i'm talking about the data inside the ContextSeeder class). Can Someone please give me an idea how to solve this issue......... thank you!!!!!

Connection string:

```
<add name="Context" connectionString="Data Source=.;database=Shop;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Do you have a connection string in your web.config for "Context"?

Comment: Bad practice -btw - to name your DbContext "Context".  Best practice would indicate something like "UserContext" or something other than simply "Context"

Comment: yes i have a connection string... database is been created but the the data that i'm inserting from the seed method is not going in...